# Edit profile doesnt edit laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, pivot

like the title says, when i go to users/1 it shows me the form , after i change something and press confirm it doesnt update, neither in the view or in the database.What can be the problem here?

my view edit.blade.php

```
  <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"><h2 style="text-align:center;">Edit Your Profile</h2></div>
                    <div class="card-body">
                      <form method="post" action="{{route('users.update',$user)}}">
                        {{ csrf_field() }}
                        {{ method_field('patch') }}
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="org_name" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Organisation Name ') }}</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input id="org_name" name="org_name" type="text" class="form-control"value="{{$user->org_name}}">

                              @error('org_name')
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @enderror
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="email" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('E-Mail Address') }}</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="email" type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ $user->email }}">

                              @error('email')
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @enderror
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="username" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Username') }}</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="username" type="username" class="form-control" name="username" value="{{ $user->username }}">

                              @error('username')
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @enderror
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="password" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Password') }}</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="password" type="password" class="form-control" name="password" >

                              @error('password')
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @enderror
                          </div>
                      </div>

                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="password-confirm" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Confirm Password') }}</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="password-confirm" type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation" required autocomplete="new-password">
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="country" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Country') }}</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="country" type="text" class="form-control" name="country" value="{{$user->country}}">

                              @error('country')
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @enderror
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="org_type" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Organisation Type') }}</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="org_type" type="text" class="form-control" name="org_type" placeholder="Vet/Uni" value="{{$user->org_type}}" >

                              @error('org_type')
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @enderror
                          </div>
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group row">
                          <label for="depart" class="col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right">{{ __('Department') }}</label>

                          <div class="col-md-6">
                              <input id="depart" type="text" class="form-control" name="depart" value="{{ $user->depart}}">

                              @error('depart')
                                  <span class="invalid-feedback" role="alert">
                                      <strong>{{ $message }}</strong>
                                  </span>
                              @enderror
                          </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="form-group row mb-0">
                          <div class="col-md-6 offset-md-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">
                              Edit
                            </button>

                      </form>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
```

my UserController

```
class UserController extends Controller
{
  public function __construct()
  {
      $this->middleware('auth');
  }

  public function edit(User $user)
  {
      $user = Auth::user();
      return view('users.edit', compact('user'));
  }

  public function update(User $user)
  {


        $this->validate(request(), [
          'org_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:users'],
          'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:users'],
          'username' => ['required', 'string','max:255', 'unique:users'],
          'password' => ['required', 'string', 'min:8', 'confirmed'],
          'country' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
          'org_type' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
          'depart' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255'],
            ]);

            $user->org_name = request('org_name');
            $user->email = request('email');
            $user->username = request('username');
            $user->password = bcrypt(request('password'));
            $user->country = request('country');
            $user->org_type = request('org_type');
            $user->depart = request('depart');


            $user->save();

            return back();

        }



  }
```

my routes

```
Route::get('users/{user}',  ['as' => 'users.edit', 'uses' => 'UserController@edit']);
Route::patch('users/{user}/update',  ['as' => 'users.update', 'uses' => 'UserController@update']);
```

Thanks in advance! I think its something wrong with the users/1/update route?

Comment: change `$this->validate(...` to `$validatedData = $this->validate(...` and dump the `$validatedData` variable

Comment: You should only send the `$user->id` to your update route and then, in your `update()` function you should do this `$userToUpdate = User::find($user->id)` and set it's new values and then `$userToUpdate->save()` and then `return redirect('etc')`

Comment: I think your request is not used correctly, you should use $request->get('email') instead of $request->('email)

Comment: @Farid hello what does this change ? i ll try it out soon

Comment: @swadhwa how do i dump the variable ?

Comment: @Ripperakos your are using $request as collection but it is an instance of http request try dumping your request to see de differences. And also check this out https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#accessing-the-request

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public function update(Rrequest $request, User $user)
 {

    $this->validate($request, [
      'org_name' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,org_name,'.$user->id,
      'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users,email,'.$user->id,
      'username' => 'required|string|max:255|unique:users,username,'.$user->id,
      'password' => 'required|string|min:8',
      'country' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'org_type' => 'required|string|max:255',
      'depart' => 'required|string|max:255',
    ]);

        $user->org_name = $request->get('org_name');
        $user->email = $request->get('email');
        $user->username = $request->get('username');
        $user->password = bcrypt($request->get('password'));
        $user->country = $request->get('country');
        $user->org_type = $request->get('org_type');
        $user->depart = $request->get('depart');

        $user->save();

    return back();

 }
```

Please user this code.

Comment: Hello friend this one gives me an error  .SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column '4' in 'where clause' (SQL: select count(*) as aggregate from `users` where `4` = Fredericko111).Why does the .$user->id return 4?

Comment: Hello I updated answer, please try with this one. Replace your update function with above.

Comment: thank You so much !!!it worked can you please explain why does this work ?

Comment: Well, this validation rule will validate if org_name is unique in users table but except itself. Your code didn't get any rule for except itself. That's why your system returned validation error. If you put toastr or alert for displaying errors, you would be able to see validation errors. I think you did put any alert in your system. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's a validation rule  you're not passing. With this:

```
'org_name' => ['required', 'string', 'max:255','unique:users'],
```

You're saying that the `org_name` must be unique, but you must specify to be unique **without itself** in update.

You can try something like this:

```
Rule::unique('users')->ignore($user->id, 'id')
```

or something like this:

```
'org_name' => 'unique:users,org_name,id_to_ignore'
```

Comment: .hello friend , i put that into my code  , but nothing changed . When i change every field in the form and press submit it just goes back to the original input fields before the changes

Comment: `$validator->messages()->all()` try this and see what it returns. Also, I suggest you use this `$validator = Validator::make($request->all(), []);`